# Using Stacks to convert numbers into characters

Tags: c++, stack

I wrote the below code to transform digits into letters. My problem is the program converts first number entered by user correctly, but it gives others same letter of first one.

For example, if the user enters the number `012` then the program will transform it into `ABC` not `AAA`.

Also I got error in `system ("pause")`, how can I fix it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int n;
    string t,u="";
    stack<string> s;
    cout<<"Enter a number n: ";
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>t;
        for(int j=0;j<t.length();j++){
            if(t[i]=='0')
                u= u+'A';
            if(t[i]=='1')
                u= u+'B';
            if(t[i]=='2')
                u= u+'C';
            if(t[i]=='3')
                u= u+'D';
            if(t[i]=='4')
                u= u+'E';
            if(t[i]=='5')
                u= u+'F';
            if(t[i]=='6')
                u= u+'G';
            if(t[i]=='7')
                u= u+'H';
            if(t[i]=='8')
                u= u+'I';
            if(t[i]=='9')
                u= u+'J';
        }
        s.push(u);
    }
    while(!s.empty()){
        cout<<s.top()<<" ";
        s.pop();
    }
    system("pause"); //error
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should indent your code. And you could reduce the 10 `if` statements to just 2 lines.

Comment: _Also I got error in system ("pause")_ : what error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop variable in the inner `for` loop is `j` but in the loop you use `i` instead of `j` :

```
for (int j = 0; j < t.length(); j++)
{
   if(t[i] == '0')  //<<<< use j instead of i here
     ...
}
```

If your code had been correctly indented/formatted, you would have found out by yourself.